# Client side logging for javascript web applications that extends console.log()

Tags: javascript, logging, ionic-framework

I have been searching the internet for a clean solution regarding client side logging for a javascript apps and have not come across an obvious choice.

My code is written with `console.log()`. I was hoping to find a javascript plugin that over-rides `console.log()`, such that i dont need to change my code, and also extends it so I can do things like programatically get the last 10 log lines to show the user?

Should I just over-ride console.log() in my application so that apart from printing to the console, it saves the logs to a global array?

I am writing mobile web apps.

Comment: *"Should I just over-ride console.log() in my application so that apart from printing to the console, it saves the logs to a global array?"* If you're set on not changing your code, yes, that would be the way to go. But I would change the code instead, call your own function so you don't have to worry about conflicts or environments that don't let you override `console.log`. One multi-file search-and-replace doesn't take long.

Comment: Is there a library that does that? I am willing to replace the code if I find a library that cleanly stores the logs for later retrieval as well as printing out

Comment: Very likely there are several. Library recommendations are off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can just override console.log function. Simple example:

```
var logs = [];
console.log = function(value) {
    logs.push(value);
}
```

And to access all parameters given to function you can use [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).